# How to dynamically set title on a Xamarin Android dialog activity?

Tags: xamarin.android

I have 2 activities on Xamarin Android. Note that the second one is styled to open as a dialog.

```
[Activity(Label = nameof(ActivityOne), HardwareAccelerated = true, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class ActivityOne : Activity { ... }

[Activity(Label = nameof(ActivityTwo), HardwareAccelerated = true, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog")]
public class ActivityTwo : Activity { ... }
```

The first one calls the second one like this:

```
var activity = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityTwo));
StartActivity(activity);
```

When the second activity opens I want to be able to set a title on the dialog dynamically.

I tried by doing this on the second activity's creation:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ActivityTwo);
    SetTitle(Resource.Id.title);

    ...
}
```

where title is defined as a "hidden" textview in ActivityTwo.axml:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/title"
  android:text="Example Title"
  android:visibility="gone" />
```

But this is what I am getting as the dialog title on running the application:

[image: dialog activity title]

Also without the SetTitle line, the title is simply "ActivityTwo". Can anybody help me figure out this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simply to use the following in OnCreate()

```
this.Title = "ExampleTitle";
```

Comment: Definitely! I missed that one. Good

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to set the title, the **Label** property on top of the Activity is the Title. This is why if you don't `SetTitle` it display **ActivityTwo** because you are telling it to do so with the use of `nameof(ActivityTwo)` .

```
[Activity(Label = "Here the title you want to show", HardwareAccelerated = true, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog")]
public class ActivityTwo : Activity { ... }
```

Regarding what you were trying, you should pass in a Resource.String to that method. Let's say you have a entry in the string.xml file **HelloActivityTitle**

```
SetTitle(Resource.String.HelloActivityTitle);
```

This will also set the title.

a third option is the `Window.SetTitle` which receives an `string` or a Java CharSequence".

```
 Window.SetTitle("Here the title you want to show");
```

**UPDATE**

```
Window.SetTitle("Here the title you want to show");
```

Should be called from the `OnResume` method.

But using the method below works calling it from the `OnCreate`

```
SetTitle(Resource.String.HelloActivityTitle);
```

Clean and rebuild your solution, just in case.

Hope it helps.-

Comment: Thanks! One thing I forgot to write was I want to set the title dynamically and none of the above solutions are working for me right now. Could you kindly update your answer to address that? I am updating the question as well.